# I get an error when I use weak password on my in ASP.Net Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, production-environment

This error does not happen when I test the application in development mode on my PC, but on the remote server it does. The app verify if user exist and the password requirements, but if I use a password like "1234" the app give me this error, but it does happen if I use a password like "@juan147-lop4s785"

[image]

This is the `launchSettings.json` file

```
{
 "iisSettings": {
   "windowsAuthentication": false,
   "anonymousAuthentication": true,
   "iisExpress": {
   "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63322",
   "sslPort": 44361
 }
},
"profiles": {
 "IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
    //"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"UniJobs": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
    //"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

and this us mi `Startup.cs` file

```
namespace UniJobs
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<Usuarios>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            //Incluye los roles de los usuarios a la app
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
                    
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your error has nothing to do with strong or weak password, you are getting SQL exception, you must Insert Data into the parent table, containing the Primary Key, before attempting to insert data into the child table containing the Foreign Key. In other words, You are trying to insert a record with a value in the foreign key column that doesn't exist in the foreign table

Comment: But, I test it and it only happens when I use a weak password... do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You most likely get an error when creating a user with a weak password and don't check if it was successful. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#password) for the default password options and how to customise them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found the error with your help. I was trying to assign the role before validation. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that when creating a user, you're not checking whether it was successful or not and therefore when your "weak password" doesn't meet the default Identity options, it fails to create the user and then the database complains about the missing foreign key, resulting in your error.

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#password) for the default Identity password options and how to customise them.

If you're using `UserManager` to create the user, you just need to check if it there were any errors and respond accordingly, something like the below:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

if(!result.Succeeded)
    return result.Errors.Select(x => x.Description);

var roleResult = await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");

if (!roleResult.Succeeded)
    return roleResult.Errors.Select(x => x.Description);
```

Comment: Exactly, that was my problem. Thanks a lot 